# Font style inconsistency on "number sign" (hashtag) and "at symbol"

Tags: style, fonts

Why number sign `"#"` (known as hashtag symbol on social media) or at sign `"@"` are not consistent with the style of other letters of alphabet?

On the other hand `"&"` or `"$"` match the style of other letters.

Using default font:

```
Style[Partition[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "#", "@", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "$", "&", "S", 
    "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}, 6] // Grid, 50]
```

[image]

Using specific font family:

```
Style[Partition[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "#", "@", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "$", "&", "S", 
    "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}, 6] // Grid, 
 FontFamily -> "Lucida Console", 50]
```

[image]

Specifically I need mono-spaced font, like for example "Lucida Console" is, but the result is simply ugly.

Do you have recommendation for a nice mono-spaced font that correctly displays both `"#"`and `"@"`?

**Update:**

I found out Mathematica itself uses weird font for `"@#"`: (see the distorted edges of `"@"`, `"#"` has no distorted edges probably just because it is composed only of horizontal and vertical lines)

```
Rasterize["A # @ $ &" , ImageSize -> 600, RasterSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

On wikipedia [number sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign) page they use non-italic font throughout the whole page but anyway the symbol of `"#"` is displayed as if it was italic. Why in mathematica we have this ugly "square like" shape and not nice "rhombus like" shape for `"#"`?

**Update 3:**

I even downloaded this beautiful [roboto font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono?query=roboto%20mono&preview.text=Almost%20before%20we%20knew%20it,%20we%20had%20left%20the%20ground.%23@&preview.text_type=custom) and I tested it in other software and it nicely display "rhombus like" shape for `"#"` - Then I used this font in Mathematica and guess what? - All letters were OK but the same ugly "square shape" for `"#"`. - **What is wrong with Mathematica?**

Comment: For some of the special operators Mathematica uses its own fonts. To get the plain number sign use the `\[NumberSign]` character.

Comment: It does not change anything for me... the style of `\[NumberSign]` is similarly inconsistent with other letters as it is with ordinary `"#"`.

Comment: I don't know how to get mathematica to stop using its special fonts, but you can at least look through all the different font variation easily with something like `Column[Style["Aa # @ \[NumberSign] "<>#, FontFamily -> #] & /@ $FontFamilies]`(or `$FontFamilies[[i ;; j]]` if you just want some)

Comment: Also, I think the inconsistency appearing with both `\[NumberSign]` and `#` for Lucida Console miight siimply have to do with Lucida Console. Check out the other characters in `Style["\[NumberSign]" <> StringJoin[Table[FromCharacterCode[n], {n, 32, 128}]], FontFamily -> "Lucida Console"]`. Compare with, say, `Times`, which appears to format as expected except for Mathematica's slot symbol. Or, it could simply be that more characters are special Mathematica characters than I thought; I'm not sure.

Comment: @thorimur I'm not sure what inconsistency you're seeing. I get a proper number sign when I run that code for both fonts?

Comment: @thorimur: You wrote: "Also, I think the inconsistency appearing with both `\[NumberSign]` and `#` for Lucida Console" might simply have to do with Lucida Console." Can't you see that the first image was created by default mathematica's font and not by Lucida console? @creidhne explained in his answer what is going on and it has nothing to do with the Lucida font but with silly default option setting.

Comment: I wrote this comment before I saw the answer, but what I meant was: from what I could tell the "inconsistency" you referred to (which applied both to `#` and `@`) was the fact that the lines were so much thinner than the letter characters. This is also true for `\[NumberSign]`. However, other characters in Lucida Console also appeared weirdly thin, and moreover, those characters varied appropriately with changes in font—unlike mathematica's `#`, suggesting it was font-specific. However, it seems that Mathematica actually uses its own fonts for all of these characters too, which surprised me!

Comment: By the way, it's worth noting that `\[NumberSign]` actually produces a different character than the typical ASCII number sign—U+F724 as opposed to U+0023, I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Style` has a [`PrivateFontOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrivateFontOptions.html) option with suboption `OperatorSubstitution`. With the default setting `"OperatorSubstitution" -> True`, special characters such as {, (, or [ are replaced by the equivalent characters in a special Wolfram System font. With the setting `"OperatorSubstitution" -> False`, such characters are not replaced. For example,

```
Style[Partition[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "#", "@", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "$", "&", "S", 
    "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}, 6] // Grid, 50,
    PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]
```

[image: font grid]

Comment: It does not work!!! I got the exact same result as without `PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstition" -> False}`. What version of Mathematica are you using? By the way It was a very bad idea to set the Style option `OperatorSubstitution` to `True` by default. We are styling strings not the code. I do not need to style code. I need to style the output of the code.

Comment: @azerbajdzan this does the exact same thing as using `\[NumberSign]`. If that's not working, the issue is in your chosen font, not on the Mathematica side.

Comment: I used it without any family font... so the default font was used.

Comment: @creidhne: You have a typo there: `PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstition" -> False}`. `OperatorSubstition` should be `OperatorSubstitution` :-). I copied your code that is why it did not work. But anyway a very bad idea to set the option to `True` by default!!!

Comment: Further more - you will  not find any reference to `PrivateFontOptions` in documentation of `Style`. It is not listed in options of `Style`. Wasted half of my day unnecessary on a trivial thing...

Comment: @azerbajdzan Often, functions have so many options that the documentation covers only the most commonly used settings. I found `PrivateFontOptions` by using `Options[Style]`. The documentation explains that the reason for the default setting is so that Mathematica can display spanning characters with changing size when an expression containing them grows larger. Thank you for catching my typo.

Comment: @b3m2a1 By the way, it's worth noting that `\[NumberSign]` actually produces a different character than the typical ASCII number sign—U+F724 as opposed to U+0023, I think. (Putting this in both comment sections just for reference.)